# Inquisitor using a baldric, bane

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, inquisitor

I would like some clarification on exactly how the [baldric, bane](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/baldric-bane/) magic item works when used with an [inquisitor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor).

Baldric, Bane

> If the wearer is an inquisitor, she is treated as five levels higher when using her bane and greater bane abilities . If the wearer is not an inquisitor, she gains the bane ability of a 5th-level inquisitor, but must first attune a light or one-handed melee weapon to the baldric by hanging it from the cloth for 24 hours, and can only use the bane ability with the attuned weapon. Attuning a new weapon to the baldric ends the attunement for the previous weapon.

So for non-inquisitor's its straight forward. A single light or one-handed melee weapon gains a 5th level inquisitors bane ability.

If an inquisitor is under level 5, would it grant the bane ability as if they were 9th level, or because it wasnt unlocked yet would the magic item do nothing for them? Same question for someone between 7-11 level would they unlock the greater bane ability?

So basically, does the item allow them to unlock bane/greater bane up to 5 levels early? Or does it only grant you increased usage once you have unlocked them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is ambiguous: it cannot be parsed out to come up with an objective “this, and only this, is exactly the rule for this situation, and no other could be understood from the text we have.” That is simply impossible; what they wrote could mean either of two entirely different answers to this question, and we have nothing more to go off of.

I will say that, while the rule itself is ambiguous, the proper ruling is not—of course it should work for lower-level inquisitors. If it gives a ***non***-inquisitor the bane ability of a 5th-level inquisitor, how absurd would it be for it to do nothing for a 3rd-level inquisitor? As far as (greater) bane is concerned, *baldric bane* means you’re actually 8th level, not 3rd, and that’s the answer. Any other ruling creates a preposterous situation where having inquisitor levels makes an inquisitor item work *less well* for you than **not** having them would.

Comment: I specifically asked if you were within 5 levels of reaching 12th for the purpose of greater bane. Of course being under 7th level this item would not have that possibility. But once you reach 7th would you gain greater bane early? Since it grants early entry into bane, the same should apply to greater bane.

Comment: @Fering Yes, of course it should. Absolutely nothing in the rule—much less my answer—suggests it would handle those differently. As I said, my ruling is “As far as (greater) bane is concerned.”

Comment: Sorry, its just that the 2nd paragraph read differently to me was all with you talking about 3rd to 8th, so thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score -1):

### The item increases the number of rounds per day you can use the ability but it does not grant earlier access to the class features.

The item states you are treated as being five levels higher when using these abilities. If you are not using these abilities, you cannot treat them as higher, hence until you do not get these abilities, its level-related variables cannot be improved.

> If the wearer is an inquisitor, she is treated as five levels higher when using her bane and greater bane abilities.

Note the difference in the wording to other items that actually give you earlier access to class features, like [Robe of Arcane Heritage](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Robe%20of%20Arcane%20Heritage). Although smite evil is usually gained at 1st paladin level, it is notable [this official FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9ni3) relates [Silver Smite Bracalet](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Silver%20Smite%20Bracelet) only to "level-based aspects" and not early access of the class feature.