# Do multiple baldric, bane items stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, stacking

Following up on my [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/180982/23058) about if [baldric, bane](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/baldric-bane/) would grant early access to bane and greater bane for an inquisitor (it does), now I wonder if two such items stack? If you had a baldric, bane and a slotless baldric, bane, would you be considered 10 levels higher for the purposes of bane?

Baldric, Bane

> If the wearer is an inquisitor, she is treated as five levels higher when using her bane and greater bane abilities . If the wearer is not an inquisitor, she gains the bane ability of a 5th-level inquisitor, but must first attune a light or one-handed melee weapon to the baldric by hanging it from the cloth for 24 hours, and can only use the bane ability with the attuned weapon. Attuning a new weapon to the baldric ends the attunement for the previous weapon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No, 2 *bane baldrics* don’t give +10 to inquisitor level

For one thing, a baldric is a chest-slot item. You can’t wear two at the same time. Whether or not you could combine two into one item, or create a bane *non*-baldric, is entirely up to the GM, and per the guidelines would cost 50% extra.

Even assuming your GM does let you get around that (and in the general case, combining or moving item effects should be a relatively low-friction ask of the GM—even the 50% extra that Paizo recommends is far, far too much in most cases), it wouldn’t help because both *bane baldric* effects are the same source. Just like having *resist energy* cast on you twice doesn’t give you resistance 20, having two *bane baldric* effects aren’t going to stack.

Technically, strict-RAW would have some pause here simply because there are rules about (non-)stacking **bonuses**, and (non-)stacking **spells**, but the more general case of non-bonus benefits from things other than spells isn’t directly discussed. However, the absence of rules on the subject (either way) doesn’t inherently allow anything; it just means you need a ruling from the GM. And the only plausible ruling I can see a GM giving is one that’s consistent with all the things we **do** have rules for. After all, for all that rule says “spells,” it’s in the “Magic Overview” section. Anyway, that rule is

> #### Same Effect More than Once in Different Strengths
>
> In cases when two or more identical spells are operating in the same area or on the same target, but at different strengths, only the one with the highest strength applies.

In this case, they don’t have **different** strengths—they have exactly the same strength—but again, it’s implausible to expect any ruling that acknowledges this as a legitimate “loophole” in the rules and allows these to stacks.

Comment: Only issue I have is that I said slotless which doubles the price of the item to get around the whole takes a slot. I rarely adjust items to another slot and prefer making them slotless or combine them, but combining didnt seem right for this case.